# Mathematica NDSolve: Is there a way to have variable coefficients?

Tags: function, variables, wolfram-mathematica, plot

Is there a way in mathematica to have variable coefficients for NDSolve? I need to vary the coefficient values and create multiple graphs, but I cannot figure out a way to do it short of reentering the entire expression for every graph. Here is an example (non-functional) of what I would like to do; hopefully it is close to working:

```
X[\[CapitalDelta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[CapitalGamma]_] = 
  NDSolve[{\[Rho]eg'[t] == 
          (I*\[CapitalDelta] - .5*\[CapitalGamma])*\[Rho]eg[t] - 
           I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Rho]ee[t] + 
           I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Rho]gg[t], 
    \[Rho]ge'[t] == (-I*\[CapitalDelta] - .5*\[CapitalGamma])*\[Rho]ge[t] + 
           I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]\[Conjugate]*\[Rho]ee[t] - 
           I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]\[Conjugate]*\[Rho]gg[t],
    \[Rho]ee'[t] == -I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]\[Conjugate]*\[Rho]eg[t] + 
           I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Rho]ge[t] - \[CapitalGamma]*\[Rho]ee[t],
    \[Rho]gg'[t] == I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]\[Conjugate]*\[Rho]eg[t] - 
           I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Rho]ge[t] + \[CapitalGamma]*\[Rho]ee[t],
    \[Rho]ee[0] == 0, \[Rho]gg[0] == 1, \[Rho]ge[0] == 0, \[Rho]eg[0] == 0},
    {\[Rho]ee, \[Rho]eg, \[Rho]ge, \[Rho]gg}, {t, 0, 12}];
Plot[Evaluate[\[Rho]ee[t] /. X[5, 2, 6]], {t, 0, 10},PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

In this way I would only have to re-call the plot command with inputs for the coefficients, rather than re-enter the entire sequence over and over. That would make things much cleaner.

PS: Apologies for the awful looking code. I never realized until now that mathematica didn't keep the character conversions.

**EDIT** a nicer formatted version:

[image]

Comment: We need a mathematica renderer! And latex and , and !!

Comment: Iam only guessing here; can you use a set-delay on the coefficients? I dont have mathematica here and i cant even GUESS what the code is doing from the SO rendering at 01:07 :)

Comment: @stefan When formatting is important I post a bitmap of the expression.

Comment: @Sjoerd yeah but as we have a mathematica tag we should somehow have a way to make the code somewhat reasonable formatted or not have the tag imo. Mathematica is prolly around 50% graphics :)

Comment: @Eliot I edited your question to include a figure of the formatted equations. It's awaiting approval. Actually, it's good for mma to convert to ASCII style. Almost no forum would be able to use the special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use `SetDelayed` ("`:=`") instead of `Set` in the function definition:

```
X[\[CapitalDelta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[CapitalGamma]_] := 
  NDSolve[{\[Rho]eg'[
      t] == (I*\[CapitalDelta] - .5*\[CapitalGamma])*\[Rho]eg[t] - 
      I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Rho]ee[t] + 
      I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Rho]gg[t], \[Rho]ge'[
      t] == (-I*\[CapitalDelta] - .5*\[CapitalGamma])*\[Rho]ge[t] + 
      I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]\[Conjugate]*\[Rho]ee[t] - 
      I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]\[Conjugate]*\[Rho]gg[t], \[Rho]ee'[
      t] == -I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]\[Conjugate]*\[Rho]eg[t] + 
      I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Rho]ge[t] - \[CapitalGamma]*\[Rho]ee[
        t], \[Rho]gg'[t] == 
     I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]\[Conjugate]*\[Rho]eg[t] - 
      I*.5*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Rho]ge[t] + \[CapitalGamma]*\[Rho]ee[
        t], \[Rho]ee[0] == 0, \[Rho]gg[0] == 1, \[Rho]ge[0] == 
     0, \[Rho]eg[0] == 
     0}, {\[Rho]ee, \[Rho]eg, \[Rho]ge, \[Rho]gg}, {t, 0, 12}];
Plot[Evaluate[{\[Rho]ee[t] /. X[5, 2, 6], \[Rho]ee[t] /. 
    X[2, 6, 17]}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Comment: Right on! Interesting: look at the behaviour of the plot for 
 PlotRange -> Automatic

Comment: @Sjoerd Convergent oscillation. `PlotRange -> Automatic` makes a user pay attention to this.

Comment: @Sjoerd and @Alexey, I prefer `PlotRange -> All`, as the oscillation is visible, but does not exceed the bounds of the display.

Comment: @Sjoerdm @rcollyer and @Alexey  I want it to go from 0 to 1. That way all the graphs are easily comparable.

Comment: @Elliot @rcollyer I agree that `PlotRange->All` looks better but in this scale we don't see any oscillation after `t=2`. In the case of `PlotRange -> Automatic` it is obvious that oscillations take place up to `t=5`. This can be useful for user himself but relatively rarely for presentation purposes.